# How to tell IE6 not to cache the html/page?

Tags: html, internet-explorer-6, http-caching

I am using the following code using PHP,

```
header("Cache-control: private");
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 2010 05:00:00 GMT');
header("Last-Modified: Mon, 26 Jul 2010 05:00:00 GMT");
header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0');
header('Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', FALSE);
header('Pragma: no-cache');
```

In all browsers it seems to be working fine but not in IE6 unless I hit Ctrl+F5 to forcefully refresh the page. How to stop caching in IE6?

Comment: People still care about IE6? Wow...

Comment: have you tried <META HTTP-EQUIV="Pragma" CONTENT="no-cache">

Comment: @Kolink - You would be surprised at the number of enterprises that simply refuse to move off of tried-and-true software. "If I can't tell it's broke, I 'aint gonna' fix it"

Comment: Maybe we should show them it's broke by not supporting them, then? :D

Comment: @Kolink : haha, yes as there are many users for it.

Comment: Is your response labeled as HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/1.0? Are you using a secure (https) connection or not? The answers to both questions matter for IE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE6 and Caching](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281/ie6-and-caching)

Comment: IE6 has at this time a market share of about 1 %. And for good reasons. Just forget about it and let the damn browser die the horrible death that it deserves...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help you: [You cannot prevent Internet Explorer 6 from caching HTTP pages by using META tags](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/937479)
Or this: [IE6 and Caching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42281/ie6-and-caching)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug. Check here:

Content with "Content-Encoding: gzip" Is Always Cached Although You Use "Cache-Control: no-cache"
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321722

Disabling gzip compression pretty much fixes it.

You could disable it just of user agents matching "MSIE 6".